# Generate iOS codesignature without the codesign(1) binary

Tags: ios, security, hash, codesign

I have scoured the internet, and was unable to find much on the specifics of how **exactly** iOS/OSX .app bundles are signed.

I know that the binary's (SHA1?) hash is taken and encrypted with asymmetric encryption with a key provided by the signer's certificate. Then info about the certificate is embedded in a file with the signed hash. I need info on how I would generate this file *without using a pre-existing utility*.

I need to do this because I want to be able to write Javascript to codesign an app with a provided certificate, but the source of the codesign(1) utility is not available.

Answer needs:
Type of hash taken from binary (and anything done to the hash).
How to embed the certificate and the hash into a file.
The output file should be the same as the one generated from the codesign(1) utility.

Comment: The `codesign` source *is* available, however you are facing a lot of work: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-55191/